# Pushing new arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

For example i have following array:

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];
```

and i have another empty array like following:

```
var b = [];
```

Here my question comes, I need to push variables from **a** to **b** but `b` must contain arrays in a such way:

b = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"]];

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried in order to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `slice` method which returns a **shallow** copy of a portion of an `array` into a **new** `array` object selected from **begin** to **end** (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

```js
let a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];
let b = [];
let chunk=2;
for (i=0,j=a.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    chunkArray = a.slice(i,i+chunk);
    b.push(chunkArray);
}
console.log(b);
```

Comment: It worked, Thanks so much!!!